# How to deal with dozens of different JSON responses?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

Throughout my app, I request JSON data from my web server and the response is almost always in a different.

For example, one response might look like this:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"token_id":"pPt9AKl0Cg","token_key":"8ax224sFrJZZkStAQuER"}}
```

While another might look like this:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"user_id":"20","username":"Bob"}}
```

And another might look like this:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"user_id":"20","stats":{"followers":"500","following":"12"}}}
```

Previously, I created a model class (Java) for each different response type. For example, for the first response above, my model class might look like this:

```
public class MyResponseModel {
        private boolean success;
        private DataModel data;

    public static class DataModel {
        private String token_id;
        private String token_key;
    }

    ...
}
```

Is this really the best way of doing this? Because if I do this for the dozen+ responses I get across my app, I'll end up with a dozen+ different model classes, one for each different response.

Are there alternatives to parsing JSON?

Thanks.

Comment: probably best to just have one request class, with the kind of structure you have now. whatever calls this class provides a callback and the request handler passes the `data` parameter back. this way the requestor doesn't need to know (or care) what it's doing. it just fires some data to the server, and then channels the response back to whatever wants it.

Comment: I'm confused, how would I parse what's in `data`?

Comment: whatever requested it should do the parsing.

Comment: Can you show in code what you mean? What would the "one request class" look like if each request's `data` has a different structure? Here is how I am requesting the data: http://pastebin.com/HbudZ6TJ

Comment: i am guessing that the different formats are meant for different purposes. for example, your first response has info about some token. fine. the second one has some info for a user. good. Now, there must be some service(s) that consume this data. Have that service/class handle the parsing

Comment: OK, how do I parse what's in `data` then? Code?

Answer (score 1):

You will need one DTO or model class for each type of response. The static typing is required to serialize/deserialize  from/to json. You can use generics to wrap the response. Refactoring your code this will be something like:

```
public class MyResponseModel <T> {
        private boolean success;
        private T data;
} 
 public class DataModel {
        private String token_id;
        private String token_key;
 }
```

Then your code can return `MyResponseModel<DataModel>` object for this scenario.

If you really want to use one class for every type of response you will need to represent all your response as key value pairs and then you can have one class containing a Map. I will not recommend that approach and would prefer to have one class for each type of response.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath , it`s only in the Java world where the default solution is to serialize/deserialize.